# Displaying the labels in a box at the top right-hand corner of the figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

As shown in the plot below, the state names are sometimes far from the line. One option to consider is not to put the labels next to the lines, but instead to include them in a box at the top right-hand corner of the figure. How can I do this?

Here is the part of my codes that I believe need to be modified.

```
    geom_line(aes(x =Year, y = Age.Adjusted.Rate, colour = State), data = d_filtered_top5_fe)+
  
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(x =Year, y = Age.Adjusted.Rate, colour = State, label = State, fontface = 'bold'), data = d_filtered_top5_fe %>% 
                             
                             filter(Year == max(Year)),
                           segment.color = 'transparent',
                           size = 2.5
  ) +
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your data using `dput(d_filtered_top5_fe)` by editing your question and pasting the output from `dput()` on it!

Answer (score 0):

Without your data, it's difficult to work out an exact solution. I guess there might be several ways to fix this. The easiest one is to use legend. We could try something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars)+
geom_line(aes(x =wt, y = mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  theme( legend.position = c(0.9, .9),
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars(am))
```

If you could provide a reproducible example, it would help others help you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How can I have two separate legends for 0 and 1 plots? Also, I was wondering if I can sort the legend labels based on their values. It appears that R sort them alphabetically.